# Java wild card BestPractices for casting

Tags: java, generics, casting, wildcard

I have researched this extensively and cant seem to find a best practice for this scenario.

```
ArrayList<GenericObject<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add( new GenericObject<Integer>(6) ); // Autoboxing
list.add( new GenericObject<String>("HI") );
if(list.get( 0 ).getGenaricValue().getClass() == Integer.class){

        GenericObject<Integer> gi = (GenericObject<Integer>) list.get( 0 );
        System.out.println("Was Integer");
        System.out.println(gi);
    }
}
```

while this block of code works the cast from GenericObject <?> to GenericObject<Integer> gives an unchecked warning. Now as you can see i have clearly checked the type with my if statement so I am not paranoid about an exception but is there a better way to do this without having to suppress the unchecked warning? Is there a best practice for this scenario? 
I have read the entire Generics oracle tutorial  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)  and i have read a lot of stackoverflow posts but none that seem to answer this problem.  any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: very contrived example? What is the point of a Generic wrapper if you add wildcard instances anyway? And by the way, the fact that the object contains an `Integer` does not mean it must be a `GenericObject<Integer>`, it could also be a `GenericObject<Number>` (and therefore allow some methods replace the "boxed" `Integer` with a `Double`.)

Comment: The best way to work around this is probably have the `GenericObject<T>` take another `Class<T>` as parameter and store it, and have a static auxiliary cast method (that suppresses unchecked warnings) that takes the `GenericObject<?>` and a `Class<T>` and casts it to `GenericObject<T>` after having verified the stored `Class<T>` value.

Comment: Thanks @mihi. I see your point about the class being being defined as type number and having some one pass an integer in. It's a good point and i had not thought of that. As to the point of this example. Say I have a table of data of all types. I want to put it in table form so i create a object called Column<T>; Column has an ArrayList of type T as well. If i put all these Columns in an ArrayList i would have ArrayList<Column<?>>; Now i need to add a new row. I would have to cast all the columns to their orignal types in order to add values to their internal Arrays

Comment: For tables with constant column types (and constant number of columns), I would try to model them as a List of Rows (each Row being a custom type that has fields of the correct types for the kind of row), instead of a list of Columns. That way, your columns have names and types, and adding a new Row is easy :)

Comment: Indeed that would be the way to do it. What I'm building is more of a frame work for creating table representations from Databases and perhaps Excel spreadsheets where the table rows are unpredictable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no better way than to suppress the warning, with an explanation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // this is okay because [insert reasoning]
GenericObject<Integer> gi = (GenericObject<Integer>) list.get( 0 );
```

Note that this isn't necessarily a good design however - it's best to avoid unchecked casts if possible, if only because they can be hard to justify. For example, what if `gi` had earlier been typed as a `GenericObject<Object>` or `GenericObject<Number>` and just happened to hold an `Integer`? It might be better to check and cast the value itself:

```
GenericObject<?> go = list.get(0);
Object obj = go.getGenericValue();
if (obj instanceof Integer) { // or obj.getClass() == Integer.class
     System.out.println("Was Integer");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think the second one is the best choice in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The end goal here though would be to then be able to use the typed generic and, for example, add another value of the same type. i.e. gi.setValue2(8); where the method is defined as  "public void setGenaricValue2( T genaricValue )."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that without the warning. The type parameter `T` of `GenericObject<T>` is always erased at runtime so even if you used the `instanceof` operator (which would get rid of the warning in other scenarios), you couldn't use it on a generic class, e.g., `if(o instanceof GenericObject<Integer>)` will not compile.